# Arduino keypad pins

Tags: arduino, keypad, pins

I've been recently working with an Arduino - trying to develop a program.  The program should find which pins a keypad button is connected to in order for it to be easier to use libraries such as "keypad".  I don't need to use a multimeter.

I'm currently working with a Megarduino and an LCD keypad shield.

This is the code that I have for scanning the keypad pins connected to the Arduino but I can't make it work.

There is previously a pin object array that has 9 pins with the following attributes: `arduinoPin`, `scannedPin`, `basePin`

```
for (int kpdBasePin=2; kpdBasePin<NUMPINS; kpdBasePin++)
{
    scanPins(kpdBasePin);    // scan all pins less than kpdBasePin.
}

void scanPins(int baseKpdPin)
{
    // Set base_pin output to LOW to begin scan process.
    int base = kpdPin[baseKpdPin].arduinoPin;
    pinMode(base, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(base, LOW);

    // Scan all pins up to, but not including, the base_pin. A LOW indicates a
    // key is being pressed.
    for (int scannedKpdPin = 1; scannedKpdPin < baseKpdPin; scannedKpdPin++)
    { 
        // Created a local variable for readability.
        int arduinoPin = kpdPin[scannedKpdPin].arduinoPin;
        int keyState = !digitalRead(arduinoPin);

        if (keyState)
        {
            storePins(scannedKpdPin, base);    //method to store both pins
        }
    }

    // End pin scanning process.
    digitalWrite(base, HIGH);
    pinMode(base, INPUT_PULLUP);
}
```

Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: Sorry but I could not understand what you are truying to achieve and why it is not working as you expected... Can you explain it better, please?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to arduino and to stackoverflow... what I'm trying to do is to let anybody connect a membrane (keypad) to the arduino, run the program, and  have an lcd showing which pair of pins is connected to a button that the person is pressing in the membrane.                                          scanPins objective is to set an arduino pin to low and then check the pins before to see if a connection is being made, then store the information. Did I explain myself better?

Comment: Ok, now it's much more easy to understand what you want... You still haven't explained why it's failing...  In my opinion this should do what you wanted..

Comment: Im not sure... as I upload the program to the arduino, I don't even get to press a button and the if(keystate) condition is fulfilled somehow...

Comment: Did you initialize all the pins to inputs WITH pullup? And what are the pins he thinks are pressed?

Comment: mostly every pair of pins, it fulfills the condition practically everytime, I haven't checked exactly the pairs that it prints.                                                     about initializing the pins... I just declare the pin array previously like this:  `kpdPin[1].arduinoPin = 32;
          kpdPin[2].arduinoPin = 34;
          kpdPin[3].arduinoPin = 36;
          kpdPin[4].arduinoPin = 38;`                                                                   and the first time I use pinMode is the one shown in scanPins()

Comment: try to put `pinMode(kpdPin[#].arduinoPin, INPUT_PULLUP);` in the setup function; of course `#` is every number you have

Comment: Thank you, I've changed it and I'll try it as soon as possible. Unfortunately, I need to first fix a problem with my arduino, for some hours I've been receiving problems while uploading a sketch. I'll try it when I fix it.